# "variable referenced from inner class must be final "problem

Tags: java

I was creating a code having 36 buttons in Jbutton array `buttons[]`.

I added an action listener to each of those using a loop

```
for (int ghe = 0; ghe < button.length; ghe++) {
    button[ghe].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button[ghe].setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

I want the clicked button to be made invisible but every time the netbeans ide gives a syntax error

> variable referenced from inner class must be final

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your method is specified, it will not work. `ghe` is of type `int`, which does not provide a `.setVisible` method.

My solution is to save the button from the array into a variable and work with it.

```
for (int ghe = 0; ghe < button.length; ghe++)
{
    JButton currentButton = button[ghe];
    currentButton.addActionListener(e -> currentButton.setVisible(false));
}
```